# Sphinx search engine, realtime index, how to set sort_mode to SPH_SORT_TIME_SEGMENTS

Tags: sphinx

Going thru all the documentation and results from google, I can't find or figure out how to set sort_mode when using realtime indexes.

I am simply using SphinxQL with pdo_mysql to connect to sphinx and running queries like:
`SELECT item_id, item_type FROM my_index WHERE MATCH (:search_string) OPTION ...`

Can I set a sort_mode? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort mode is not directly exposed. But can do everything it can do in other ways.

For time-segments see

http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2010/06/27/doing-time-segments-geodistance-searches-and-overrides-in-sphinxql/